# Page repeatedly refreshed after overlay closed youtube video

Tags: jquery

I am having the youtube video working on the overlay.I managed to stop the video after closing the button, but my page is getting refreshed repeatedly and i am not getting the cursor over the page, so that i could use the other videos..

Any help will be highly appreciable.. Thanks

Here is my page you can check by visiting, click on the video 13 only, which is working for the overlay only..

```
http://excitedcashflow.com/tpl/ebay_videos_2.php
```

here is my code for the jquery used to make this

```
$jq(function () {
var player = $f("player", "", {
  clip: {
    baseUrl: "",
    scaling: "fit",

  }
});

$jq("a[rel]").overlay({
  mask: {
    color: '#000',
    opacity: 0.2
  },
  onLoad: function () {
  // player.play(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));

  },
  onClose: function () {
  $('player').get(0).stopVideo();
    player.unload();
  }
});  });  $jq(document).ready(function() {
// $jq('#clicked').trigger("click");
setTimeout(function () {
  $jq('#clicked').trigger('click');
}, 1000);

// stops the video when modal closes
$jq('.close').click(function(){
  var repeat = function() {
    $jq('#clearmySound').attr('src', '');

  }
  setInterval(repeat, 500);
});  });
```

Comment: <div id="overlay"><a class="close"></a>
<div>
     <iframe width="510" height="380" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/upr_HlVbV6U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="clearmySound"></iframe>

Comment: I face this problem before, my trick was to set the src attribute like this --> src="". But if you open the video again, user will lose the progression of the video

Comment: @lateek35 - my problem is that the page is getting refreshed repeatedly, i am unable to check whether the same video will open or not, Please help

Comment: What is the function of unload() ? Think the problem is here

Comment: @lateek35 no unload() function, i have tried to remove player.unload() the same refreshing problem is repeating..Any help

Comment: Oh, my bad !
First, why are you using a setInterval for clearing the src attribute ?
That's what cause your refresh problem.

Comment: @lateek35 - if i remove the setInteval then the background video does not stop, you check the source code of the page and try in your browser.

Comment: Yes but just put $jq('#clearmySound').attr('src', ''); 
Don't put it into a setInterval